# Leading whitespaces being removed with the verbatim package

Tags: formatting

The following is rendering with leading white space removed inside the verbatim block. In addition, the
indentation is not preserved. I would like to keep both the leading white space and the indentation.

```
Test Algorithm
\begin{verbatim}
    top = 0
    bottom = last
    while top < bottom
        middle = (top + bottom) / 2
    end while
\end{verbatim}
```

Here is the entire file:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{verbatim }
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
    top = 0
    bottom = last
    while top < bottom
        middle = (top + bottom) / 2
    end while
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your claim, about leading space characters being removed inside a `verbatim` environment, does not appear to be correct. To demonstrate this, just load the `showframe` package in the preamble and recompile; you'll see that the leading whitespace and the indentation are all nicely there.

Comment: @Mico I added the package showframe and it shows that the leading space is being removed. I am using TeXstdio. I then tired the same file on Overleaf and there the white space is being preserved.

Comment: @Bob, I tried your MWE in TeXstudio, and I am getting the whitespace just as Mico did.  Have you run just your MWE in TeXstudio, or could it be some other line in your document that causes the problem?

Comment: @fiat96 It could be some other line, so I have included the entire file in the post. It does not have showframe in it.

Comment: @Bob I compiled the whole thing, and I still get the whitespace.  All I can think of now is that a TeXstudio setting may somehow be messing with your compilation, and at that point I'm out of my depth.

Comment: Please run the example at https://gist.github.com/moewew/93d9ebd9ff930bd1e1330b983e0e7451 and post a screenshot of the output and the `.log` file. Both your MWE and the one in the link compile to output *with* spaces for me.